# Turning MapsForge project into a navigation app using Graphhopper

Tags: java, android, navigation, graphhopper, mapsforge

I am trying to make  a basic navigation app from my MapsForge project. It seems there is no MapsForge library for Navigation. I found out that it could be done with Graphhopper but I couldn't find any Jar files of it either. Is there any Graphhopper libraries that i can add to my project or is there any other way including Graphhopper to my project?

Answer (score 0):

Use maven or gradle via the snippet provided at https://graphhopper.com/#community or see [the sample application in the repo](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/tree/master/android)